# .bat script for running jmx console: problems with paths

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, jmx, jconsole

I've been struggling to create a .bat script for Windows for running the JMX console. I've managed to do it with some tricks, but there must be something very wrong I'm doing and I haven't found a solution after investigating and googling quite a bit, and many trials. If this question is a duplicate, I'll be happy to remove it.

This is my original script (an attempt to translate the script that I have running for Mac and Linux)

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jconsole.exe -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%MY_JCONSOLE_PATH%\opendmk_jmxremote_optional_jar-1.0-b01-ea.jar service:jmx:jmxmp://<host>:<port>
```

The problems that I've faced:

- `jconsole.exe` does not seem to run properly unless I do a `cd` to `$JAVA_HOME\bin`
- cannot make the script (or maybe the `jconsole`) understand `%JAVA_HOME%\lib`, and I had to add a new environment variable

This is my working version to address the problems above:

```
set MY_PATH=%cd%

cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin

jconsole.exe -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_BIN%\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_BIN%\tools.jar;%MY_PATH%\opendmk_jmxremote_optional_jar-1.0-b01-ea.jar service:jmx:jmxmp://<host>:<port>
```

But it is not very clean and I'd just like to know what mistake(s) I'm doing. I'd just like to know!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you leave a problem for a couple of days and with a fresh mind you solve it... in case it helps anybody, solution is as follows,

```
set MY_PATH=%cd%

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jconsole.exe" -J"-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%MY_PATH%\opendmk_jmxremote_optional_jar-1.0-b01-ea.jar" service:jmx:jmxmp://<host>:<port>
```

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the directory `Program Files` has a space on it, however the double quotes `"` cannot be put just anywhere (e.g. I tried to define the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk...` but that did not help.